# Running a Scala Script with external dependencies

Tags: java, bash, scala, scripting, jvm

I have the following jars under /Users/joe/.scala/lib:

```
commons-codec-1.4.jar       
httpclient-4.1.1.jar        
httpcore-4.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar   
httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar  
httpmime-4.1.1.jar
```

Below is my test.sh written in scala.

```
#!/bin/sh -v
L=`cd /Users/joe/.scala/lib;pwd`
cp=`echo $L/*.jar|sed 's/ /:/g'`
echo $cp
exec scala -classpath $cp $0 $@
!#
println(new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient())
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
$ ./test.sh 
#!/bin/sh -v
L=`cd /Users/joe/.scala/lib;pwd`
cd /Users/joe/.scala/lib;pwd
cp=`echo $L/*.jar|sed 's/ /:/g'`
echo $L/*.jar|sed 's/ /:/g'
echo $cp
/Users/joe/.scala/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:/Users/joe/.scala/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/Users/joe/.scala/lib/httpclient-4.1.1.jar:/Users/joe/.scala/lib/httpclient-cache-4.1.1.jar:/Users/joe/.scala/lib/httpcore-4.1.jar:/Users/joe/.scala/lib/httpmime-4.1.1.jar
exec scala -classpath $cp $0 $@
/Users/joe/Desktop/scala/./test.sh:7: error: object httpclient is not a member of package org.apache.commons
println(new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient())
                               ^
one error found
```

However, simple ones without any classpath dependencies work though:
hello.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
exec scala "$0" "$@"
!#

println(new java.util.Date())
```

Any idea what I am  doing wrong in the first example? Alternatively, what is the best way to set classpath dependencies when working with scala scripts?

Comment: Is it possible that the error is correct for the simple reason that your jar does not contain `org.apache.commons.httpclient`?

Comment: @Langali: Why have your questions been replaced by "test test test test"? Stop it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think with 4.1.1 the class is org.apache.http.client.HttpClient instead of org.apache.commons.httpclient, and it's an interface.  So you might want

```
new org.apache.http.client.DefaultHttpClient()
```

instead of

```
new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient()
```

It might well have been different in an earlier version.

Comment: @Langali: We've all been there.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not going to answer your question, but you might be interested in this.

Suppose you download and install [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Setup) (version 0.10.0 or higher), and create a shell script called "[scalas](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Scripts)":

```
java -Dsbt.main.class=sbt.ScriptMain \
     -Dsbt.boot.directory=/home/user/.sbt/boot \
     -jar sbt-launch.jar "$@"
```

And then you write your script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env scalas
!#

/***
scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.4", 
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.1.1",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.1",
  "commons-logging" % "commons-logging" % "1.1.1",
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient-cache" % "4.1.1", 
  "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpmime" % "4.1.1"
)
*/

println(new org.apache.http.client.DefaultHttpClient())
```