# Does Scala having an interpreter give Scala projects the option to execute them either compiled or interpreted?

Tags: scala

I'm aware that scala has an interpreter and scala is statically typed. So I'm wondering if it is possible to execute scala projects in both Java and PHP style ?

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP-style"?
Scala does not have a real interpreter - though you can type commands to a read-eval-print-loop (REPL) which will compile them right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need an interpreter to test your code? Then type `scala` to get interpreter and use `:load` command to load scala file.

I don't know exactly what is the PHP style, but yes, you can execute scala interactively, static typing is not a big issue here. If you need to exectue simple script that's easy (code from "Getting started in Scala"):

```
  #!/bin/sh
  exec scala "$0" "$@"
  !#
  object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world! " + args.toList)
    }
  }
  HelloWorld.main(args)
```

If you have .jar dependencies in your script than things got more complicated,because you need to pass this jar dependencies to the scala interpreter. [here is example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350876/running-a-scala-script-with-external-dependencies)
As of current date this method doesn't allow you to modularize scripts into the multiple files, but here is [workaround](http://www.crosson.org/2012/01/simplifying-scala-scripts-adding.html)

If you have `sbt` project you can type `console` from sbt shell to get a scala interpreter with correct classpath and dependencies. Also sbt itself has a 'script' mode which works quite like `groovy`'s embedded dependency menegment.

Also scala compiler is embeddable) [This](http://code.google.com/p/scalascriptengine/) project helps to dynamically compile/recompile scala files and load them into the jvm.